# Does a BinaryFormatter consume the bytes if an exception throws

Tags: c#, networking, tcpclient, networkstream, binaryformatter

I'm trying to use a `BinaryFormatter` to send and receive message in C# using a `NetworkStream` ( got from a `TcpClient` ). 
When I do `formatter.Deserialize( Stream )`, the program block until the client send something.
I am wondering, if I set a timeout on the TcpClient, is the `BinaryFormatter` going to consume the bytes it has read before the exception throws ?

Is theres an other way to do this ?

Is it possible to check if the entire message is receive, without any timeout ? ( Something faster )

Thank you,

Comment: Try this example implementation of async sockets from MS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a

Comment: If you set a timeout on the TcpClient, and that timeout expires, then you are done with that connection. It won't matter at that point whether `BinaryFormatter` did or did not consume any bytes.

Comment: @PeterDuniho i mean set a timeout on the `NetworkStream`

Comment: Doesn't matter. Whether you go through the `Socket`, the `TcpClient`, or the `NetworkStream`, they all do the same thing: set the timeout in the socket itself. When that timeout expires, the socket is no longer valid for use.